# stochastic differential equations via Hida distributions?

Tags: stochastic-differential-equations

Can one prove the solvability of stochastic Ito differential equations via [Hida distributions](http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/7103)?

Comment: You need to be more precise on your question, give a toy example/ definition of hida distributions etc.

Comment: I added a link and corrected the sentence.